# Blazor "Work with radio buttons" enum issue

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to implement the "Work with radio buttons" example found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#work-with-radio-buttons however I ran into difficulty when trying to use it with an enum.

```
@page "/RadioButtonExample"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using MyApp.Shared

<h1>Radio Button Group Test</h1>

<EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    @foreach (int status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)))
    {
        <label>
            <InputRadio name="rate" SelectedValue="status" @bind-Value="model.Status" />
            @status
        </label>
    }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<p>You chose: @model.Status</p>

@code {
    private Administrator model = new Administrator();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valid");
    }
}
```

My enum is defined as below

```
public enum Status
{
    Disabled = 0,
    Enabled = 1
}
```

The error I receive is the below which I understand why I'm getting, however, I'm not sure how best to resolve.

TypeInference.CreateInputRadio_0(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, object, int, TValue, int, TValue, int, EventCallback, int, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use foreach loop over enum for radio button, Microsoft has an example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#radio-buttons

```
<p>
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="starship.Manufacturer">
        Manufacturer:
        <br>
        @foreach (var manufacturer in (Manufacturer[])Enum
            .GetValues(typeof(Manufacturer)))
        {
            <InputRadio Value="manufacturer" />
            <text>&nbsp;</text>@manufacturer<br>
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
</p>
```